# High vif after squaring the regressors

Tags: variance-inflation-factor

If I have 2 regressors in regression, with low vif (less than 5 for each of them), after squaring them, the vif increased significantly (more than 10), in the course, we haven’t covered how to fix high vif.
In the excercise, the regressors were squared to make the relationship linear between the regressors and the output.

**So, is it possible to interprete the parameter estimates of these regressors, while having very high vif due to the squaring of the regressors?**

Comment: One way to fix this is to mean-center the variables before squaring.

Comment: @Peter That's unlikely to continue linearizing the relationship unless the variables have means very close to zero in the first place.  As far as the question goes, the answer is "yes, of course it's possible to interpret the estimates -- in the usual ways" and an appropriate followup is "why is a high VIF even a problem in this instance?"